# Why does Python show errors in lines that don't exist in my code while trying to automize my WhatsApp messages using pywhatkit library?

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, line, whatsapp

I am trying to automize my WhatsApp messages with python and the pywhatkit library and even though I followed the exact instructions of the tutorial I was using, it doest work at all. My code looked like this:

```
import pywhatkit

phone_number = input("Enter phone number: ")
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(phone_number, "Hello", 16, 34)
```

Even though this worked in the tutorial I saw, it doesn't work for me and I get the following errors when I run the programm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/toniokurth/PycharmProjects/Whatsapp_automation_24.5.2023/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "/Users/toniokurth/PycharmProjects/Whatsapp_automation_24.5.2023/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.handwriting import text_to_handwriting
  File "/Users/toniokurth/PycharmProjects/Whatsapp_automation_24.5.2023/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/handwriting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/toniokurth/PycharmProjects/Whatsapp_automation_24.5.2023/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Users/toniokurth/PycharmProjects/Whatsapp_automation_24.5.2023/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with LibreSSL 2.8.3. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168
```

Thats a lot of mistakes for a very few lines of code and here are my problems:

1. Python doesn't show any error or warning prior to when I executed the code
2. Python refers to lines that don't even exist in my code, my code has 4 lines and they are honestly telling me about mistakes in lines 12, 43 and 38, Im sorry but wtf is that about. Im fairly new to coding and I would love it if Python would be a little more precise as to what my mistakes exactly mean and where they are in the code.

Im sorry if my question is stupid, but I've spent like two hours trying do fix these mistakes and I am pretty tired and frustrated, because I can't improve my coding skills if I can't learn from my mistakes and I can't learn from my mistakes when I don't understand them.

If anyone could muster a shred of their time to help me, I would be very grateful and happy, Thanks

I did everything exactly like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQQTABNMZCE
I am not here to criticize the video, but clearly what he did doesn't work for everyone (or I am just very fuck**g stupid, which is entirely possible as well)

Comment: It looks like your libraries aren't installed properly, you have version mismatches between them.